# Set root path for tags xtype in aem

Tags: aem

Am using **xtype tag**, where I have to select tags in the dialog. Here I need to set the tags path so I can use selective tags from the specified path.

Currently it is defaulted to **/etc/tags** and showing all the tags.
I can use namespaces but it works with namespaces that you create directly under /etc/tags (like : **/etc/tags/maintag**)

Is there any way where I can set the root path like: **/etc/tags/maintag/subtag**?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the `tags` xtype that you're using, you should be looking at the docs for [TagInputField](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.tagging.TagInputField)

What you're looking for is the `tagsBasePath` property. Setting it to `/etc/tags/maintag/subtag` should do the trick.